# How can I install Firebase Analytics pod without other google libraries?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I need to add Firebase Analytics pod into my xcode project. I added the line:

pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.13.0'

and called "pod install" in the terminal, but it installed some other libraries:

[image: libraries installed]

How can I install this pod without installing all these libraries, or at least remove some of them?

If I must install all these pods - can I initiate firebase analytics only?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a quick scan, these are all libraries that the Firebase Analytics SDK depends on for its operation. For example, the Analytics SDK uses the `GoogleDataTransport` and `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport` libraries to help encode the data and send it to the server.

There is no way to use the Firebase Analytics SDK without those libraries.